# Mandatory language for ResourceBundle.getBundle() when using classes instead of properties files or ListResourceBundles

Tags: java, internationalization

If I have properties like this:

- I18N.properties
- I18N_en.properties
- I18N_en_US.properties

I can use `ResourceBundle.getBundle(Locale.FRANCE)` and it will load the default properties (I18N.properties). This also works if I use ListResourceBundle classes instead of properties.

However if I try to use ResourceBundle classes, the rule seems different, I need to have at least a `I18N_xx.class`, it will not use the default `I18N.class`: for instance locale `en_CA` will load `I18N_en.class` but locale `fr_FR` (or `Locale.FRANCE`) won't load `I18N.class`, instead I get:

> Can't find bundle for base name I18N, locale fr_FR

Furthermore if I add an I18N.properties file, then the getBundle() will find it...

Is is normal behavior? Am I missing something? [The doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.ResourceBundle.Control)) seems to hint that this is normal (note that the candidates lists in the examples end on `{base name}_{lang}`), but if this is so I don't see the rationale? Why should the base default be a properties file?

Comment: Which JDK are you using? I have similar setup on JDK14, it is happy using the I18N.class for Locale FRANCE when no I18N_fr / I18N_fr_FR as class or properties, and it will scan for I18N_en and I18N_en_GB class and properties (in my case) as well

Comment: Using JDK11. eventually found my mistake, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the real answer is, the constructor of my base `ResourceBundle` class was not public...

However, while investigating this I found another weirdness:

It appears that if it cannot find a resource for the language, instead of going to the base file it tries with the default locale: if my default locale is an English-based locale, say, `en_IE` then asking for an `fr_FR` resource yields the `en` one, and if the  default is `en_US`, `fr_FR` resources come from the `en_US` bundle.

In a server, that would be a pain because a server-wide default language wouldn't yield an adequate behavior for all users, but it appears that Java defines a language/country neutral `Locale.ROOT` static for this purpose.